# Hightcharts paints first tick out of the container

Tags: highcharts

Using Hightcharts the first tick is painted out of container.

[image]

I´m using highcharts with gwt, I set the chart as datetime and also I set the tickInterval option with 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (1 month in ms) and everything seems correct but the first tick is painted outside of the chart.

Any idea?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't appear to reveal much about the problem you're having. Can you explain the problem a little better and possibly provide code examples to allow us to replicate this?

Comment: I think this is some old bug in Highcharts. It should be resolved in 4.1.9, however, looks like gwt adapter by moxie group is quite outdated, see [info](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/download.jsp) - 4.1.5.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the highstock version and now it works fine.